# NewBie: How do I pass a callback to another activity

Tags: android

I have a simple activity (Activity1) which will create a callback using 'ActionCallback'. I am executing this callback from Activity1 but the results appear after some time due to network delays, I need to show result of callBack on another view which is Activity2 (extends ListActivity).

I dont want to wait in Activity1 (for user experience) for the callback to complete and then send to Activity2 using Intent.putExtra()

My question is, how do I pass this callback to Activity2 from Activity1? Can this be done? Or is there a better way to program this logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use startActivityForResult & explore it so you will get better way to do whatever you want in callback

Comment: Isn't startActivityForResult() for retrieving data from a returning Intent (Actvity)?
My scenario is, I want to launch the Activity2 (by passing the callback instance) and wait for the callback result in Activity2

Comment: while starting new Activity create 1 thread which will do your callback work & use your custom handler class which will do next processing `Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //code to be executed after task finished
        }
    };`

Answer (score 1):

If the network action is directly related to the activity switch you may want to just pass all the information gathered to Activity2 and start the network call there.

Or you could send a broadcast from your async task when you have loaded the information and register any activity for the broadcast that needs to show the information.

Comment: ok, I will try this.
Can you point me to any sample code? Or some online help regarding this?

Comment: But i still need the network instance to be passed to Activity2 because network instance is created in Activity1.

How do I pass this network object to Activity2?
putExtra() does not take 'object'